# SSRS - how to use 3 if statements, one of which is a blank value

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report in which one of the columns returns a DB field which can be 1 of 3 possible outcomes - 1, 0 or blank/"".
From what I can see, I think the problem here is that the field is blank rather than a NULL value, so any expressions I use seem to result in a #Error.
So far I have managed two different expressions which yield two halves of the results I need:

```
=IIF(Fields!Field1.Value = 1, "Yes", IIF ({Fields!Field1.Value = 0}, "No", "Unanswered"))
```

The above gets me 1 = "Yes", 2 = "No" and "" = #Error.

```
=IIF(Fields!Field1.Value="","Unanswered",Fields!Field1.Value)
```

This second one gets me 1 = 1, 0 = 0 and "" = "Unanswered".

Is there a way I can combine these and have the results appearing as 1 = "Yes", 0 = "No" and "" = "Unanswered"?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I think Alan's answer would work for you, but I think your first expression should work if you remove those funky brackets.  Should be `=IIF(Fields!Field1.Value = 1, "Yes", IIF((Fields!Field1.Value = 0), "No", "Unanswered"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this SWITCH expression.

```
=SWITCH (
        Fields!Field1.Value = 1, "Yes",
        Fields!Field1.Value = 0, "No",
        True, "Unanswered"
    )
```

The final `True` acts like and `else`.

If this does not work, you may need to cast the field to text and check as follows

e.g. `CStr(Fields!Field1.Value) = "1", "Yes",`